# How to uninstall an app whose folder is deleted

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

There is an app (pycharm) that has a shortcut that leads to a place that doesn't exist however the app still works somehow.

I downloaded the app once before then delted its folder permenantly on the c disk (that was a huge mistake, I am aware of it now).

I tried unistalling but I got a message saying that there was an error unintalling the app may have been uninstalled do you want to removed from installed apps and I said yes.

However when I type the app's name in searchbox I get a shortcut with no icon of the app that somehow opens the app that is working.
I tried to see where the shortcut leads but that location doesn't exist. I tried windows unistall troubleshooter but the app is not listed and i don't know the product key.

Answer (score 1):

Find the application and download it.

Restart your computer. While not obligatory, restart is a good idea to help ensure the system has a fresh start from which to do an installation.

Now install the App.

Now you should be able to properly uninstall it.

This is the normal approach for this situation.

If this approach fails to work, then there has been some collateral damage. A Repair Install can be used but the Keep Everything approach is unlikely to work.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts.

First try Keep Just Data (you keep the data but have to reinstall Apps.

Then if that does not work, select Keep Nothing and reinstall Windows.  Ensure you have a good backup first.

Comment: Why the restart after downloading and before installing?

Comment: Because I think that is as good idea to restart before installing to make sure that step works

Comment: I tried that and the shortcut still somehow works.

Comment: If the standard approach does (did) not work, then the deletion of the folder has caused some collateral damage. I posted steps for a repair install

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using third party apps like [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/) for ease of use and to fix your issue.

For to resolve your issue you have to download the pro version of the software which you can use it for 15 days as a trial. Install the program and launch it. Then click on `Forced Uninstall` and search the program that you want to remove it(in your case Pycharm). Then after that all you have to do is follow the instructions that will be displayed on the program and it'll completely remove the program including folders and registry entries.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have used Revo Uninstall and it also causes collateral damage in some cases. This case where the folder was deleted may prevent Revo from working properly